# Deploy Shared DLL without GAC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gac

I have been able to avoid gac with the following

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MyCode" publicKeyToken="123" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="file:///E:/shared/MyCode.dll" />        
  </dependentAssembly>
```

This works fine, however i would like to specify multiple paths.  Is this possible?

i.e. e:/shared/mycode.dll as well as c:/shared/mycode.dll

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - why do you need to reference the same assembly twice?

Comment: We have 40+ some web sites that reference the same dll.  In the future we want to update the dll and all related web sites will be updated with the new dll.  Typically this has been done with GAC.  As GAC is going away we would like to move towards codebase attribute in web.config to specify the shared assembly.

Comment: David, that still doesn't answer why you want to specify multiple paths.

Comment: Ant P asked why we would have a shared assembly, hence my answer.  Now if you are asking why multiple paths...cause e:\ is location on our production servers but say locally on workstations it would be like c:\ (cause we dont have an e:\)

Comment: What about using config transforms?

Comment: I had considered that, however currently we are not using transforms on our web.configs (i recognize that is an option).  I was hoping there was a way of comma delimiting paths or putting in multiple codebase elements

Comment: How about `subst e:\ c:\ ` on your local boxes? https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true